# include file menu active page colored link in asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have too many pages. when I change something on menu I have to change every page. I don't want to write navigation menu for every page again and again, so I used include file navigation menu.
I don't know asp too much but I want to use it.

navigation.inc sample:

```
<a class="nav-link active" href="link1.asp">Link 1</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="link2.asp">Link 2</a>
```

there is a class called active. paints the navigation link in blue. when I navigate to link2 page I want to do this

```
<a class="nav-link" href="link1.asp">Link 1</a>
<a class="nav-link active" href="link2.asp">Link 2</a>
```

how can I that with asp classic? I tried something but it's looks ridiculous. is there any easy and professional way?

thanks for all information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an include in all your pages :

```
<%
...
%>
<!--#include file="nav.asp"-->
<%
...
%>
```

And your `nav.asp` page :

```
<%
curPageName = Request.ServerVariables("URL")

if curPageName = "link1.asp" then
    %>
    <a class="nav-link active" href="link1.asp">Link 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="link2.asp">Link 2</a>
    <%
end if

if curPageName = "link2.asp" then
    %>
    <a class="nav-link" href="link1.asp">Link 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link active" href="link2.asp">Link 2</a>
    <%
end if
%>
```

You can simplify your `nav.asp` page by adding a custom `iif` function to vbscript

```
<%
function iif(condition, t, f)
    if condition then
        iif = t
    else
        iif = f
    end if
end function

curPageName = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
%>
<a class="nav-link<%=iif(curPageName = "link1.asp", " active", "")%>" href="link1.asp">Link 1</a>
<a class="nav-link<%=iif(curPageName = "link2.asp", " active", "")%>" href="link2.asp">Link 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<!--#include virtual="/PathToYour/Page/navigation.asp"-->` in the page where you want your `navigation` page to appear.

navigation.asp:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="link1.asp">Link 1</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="link2.asp">Link 2</a>
```

And then use some jQuery to automate your "active" or "currentPage" class on links.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Loop through all <a href> elements and see if it matches current page, if it does add "active" class to that link
        $("a").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("href") === window.location.pathname) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            } else if ($(this).attr("href") === window.location.href) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            } else if ($(this).attr("href") === window.location.pathname + window.location.search) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

sample home.asp (with all kind of "templates" --- header, footer, functions, etc.):

```
<% Option Explicit %>
<!-- #include virtual="/local/scripts/vbs/settings.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/global/scripts/vbs/db.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/global/scripts/vbs/format.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/global/scripts/vbs/pages.asp" -->

<!-- #include virtual="/global/shared/templates/inc-doctype.asp" -->
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title><%=PageTitle & gWebTitle%></title>
<meta name="description" content="<%=TitlePageHeading%>">
<!-- #include virtual="/global/shared/templates/inc-meta.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/global/shared/templates/inc-styles.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/global/shared/templates/inc-scripts.asp" -->
</head>
<body>

<!-- #include virtual="/local/scripts/templates/header.inc" -->

<%
    'Main Page Content Goes Here
%>

<!-- #include virtual="/local/scripts/templates/footer.inc" -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Loop through all <a href> elements and see if it matches current page, if it does add "active" class to that link
        $("a").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("href") === window.location.pathname) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            } else if ($(this).attr("href") === window.location.href) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            } else if ($(this).attr("href") === window.location.pathname + window.location.search) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```